# Create Custom folder inside WEB-INF/classes

Tags: tomcat, classloader

I am deploying my web application in tomcat6.0 . As per the requirement i have to deploy it inside some custom folder . By default all my class file will be store(in tomcat) inside the

`WEB-INF\classes\package-name\ClassName.`

But here i wants to put it inside my custom folder. So the above one will looks

`WEB-INF\classes\mycustomfolder\package-name\ClassName.`

Here mycustomfolder is not a package name it is just an folder. So when deploy with the custom folder structure my application throwing ClassNotFoundException. Is there anyway for this one to make work

Comment: What are you trying to achieve whit that custom folder?

Comment: In future if some of the clients wants to change the particular functionality , we dont want to create the new project instead of that we will create one more folder inside the web-inf\classes\client2. All client2 calls will refer classes only from the client2 folder

Answer (score 0):

Edit the **.classpath** file of your WAR project to point to the new directory location:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>

    ...

    <classpathentry kind="output" path="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/mycustomfolder"/>

</classpath>
```

Comment: If i set it like above inside my war file , all server can refer the classes from my custom folder ?